# Credit card jquery plugin doesn't reset after error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using [Jesse Pollak's Credit Card plugin](https://github.com/jessepollak/card), and I'm trying to "reset" everything (inputs and card info that goes in the image) after an ajax response.

I've managed show the error message and give "" value to the inputs, but the info in the image stays there. Screenshot here:

[image]

```
$.ajax({
    type: form.attr("method"),
    url: form.attr("action"),
    dataType: "json",
    data: form.serialize()
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.forma_pagamento == "cielo") {
        if (data.codigo != "6" || data.codigo != "4") {
            $(".loading").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $(".result-error-message").html("Transaction not authorized. Try again with a different credit card");
            $(".result-error-message").fadeIn().delay(6000).fadeOut();
            $("#btn-finalizar-compra").prop("disabled", false);
            $(".cc-num,.cc-name,.cc-expiry,.cc-cvc").val("");
        } else {
            location.href = "finalizar-compra/obrigado";
        }
    } else {
        location.href = "finalizar-compra/obrigado";
    }
});
e.preventDefault();
```

Any clues?

Comment: I would imagine that the graphic is updated on the `change` event of those inputs. If so, the issue is that `val()` does not raise that event, so you could try raising it manually: `$(".cc-num,.cc-name,.cc-expiry,.cc-cvc").val("").change();`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, didn't work.

Comment: Try simulating a keypress instead: `var e = jQuery.Event("keydown"); e.which = 8; $(".cc-num,.cc-name,.cc-expiry,.cc-cvc").val("").trigger(e);`

Comment: Nothing, @RoryMcCrossan...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to reset it by choosing the default parameters, like this:

```
$(".jp-card-number").html("•••• •••• •••• ••••");
$(".jp-card-name").html("Jose da Silva");
$(".jp-card-expiry").html("••/••");
$(".jp-card-cvc").html("•••");
```

Not the prettiest of solutions, but worked anyway!